# How do I reload a relation collection in laravel?

Tags: php, collections, laravel, laravel-4, relationship

In Laravel, after using `attach()` or `detach()` to add or remove something from a relation, the collection has not changed. So if I have a model whose relation contains `[1, 2]`, after this:

```
$model->relation()->detach(1);
$model->relation()->attach(3);
```

it will still contain `[1, 2]`! How do I refresh it?

Answer (score 149):

You can easily tell laravel to load a relation with a single command:

```
$model->load('relation');
```

Will tell it to refresh the relation collection, and `$model->relation` will now show the correct values.

Also unloading a relation will be like this:

```
$model->unsetRelation('relation')
```

Comment: This is also handy for reloading a model after doing a `$model->relation()->save($relation)` situation.

Comment: You can also do `unset($model->relation)`

Comment: @SilverPaladin Might be better to save it like this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models

Answer (score 9):

From Laravel 7.x you can use `$model->refresh()` for refreshing the model and it's relations.

[Here the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method)

Comment: Correct. This is now the simplest way.

Answer (score 7):

either just `unset` it and let the system reload on demand.

```
unset($model->relation)
```

or

```
$model->unsetRelation('relation');
```

And let it be loaded on request.

Answer (score 5):

Conclusion: three solutions in here

```
$model->load('relation');

unset($model->relation);

$freshCollection = $user->roles()->get();`
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to use Eloquent query builder:

```
$freshCollection = $user->roles()->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to force all your relations to reload on an as-needed basis and you're inside your model, you can use:

```
$this->relations = [];
```

Comment: this is not intuitive, does it mean that every time when my relation has no items it makes a DB request?

Comment: yes, when you do `$user->posts` it checks the `relations` property to see if the related collection has already been retrieved. If not it'll load it from the database.

Answer (score 1):

$model->fresh() did the job for me.
Wanted to replicate multiple levels of nested models then do a loop over them.
Laravel was caching the previous relation and not the new "current" relation.